# unable to delete large folder from icloude drive

Tags: mac, icloud

I am unable to delete large folders from my icloud drive.( I have tried it both from my phone and from icloud.com) get an error saying “There was a problem deleting “folder name” try again later”

I have been trying to delete it for weeks now!! I have so many folders with lots of sub directories. It works when I delete files individually. However I don’t have the luxry nor the patience to spend days for it.

Comment: Sounds like an iCloud bug. Perhaps try to give AppleCare a call